# Compare 2 Object Arrays, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Array 1:
`[ user:{id:1,votes:9}, user:{id:2,votes:3} ]`

Array 2:
`[ user:{id:1,votes:10}, user:{id:2,votes:5}, user:{id:3,votes:1} ]`

Using Node.js, what is the most efficient way to isolate the unique user based on id on it's own?

Using For loops and ForEach loops, I can't figure it out. Underscore is an option, but I still can't figure out a function process. Many thanks.

(I have no control over the way the data comes to me, modifying the array or the object isn't an option sadly)

Comment: Both of those statements/arrays are invalid in JavaScript.

Comment: What is "efficient"? Least processing power? Fastest execution? Least code? Easiest to mainatain?

Comment: @RobG Least code and easiest to maintain. I accepted the answer below. I forgot to consider .map.

@ undefined That is the data passed to me by an API that I'm using. I create my own user objects, and use the data I get passed on certain events to maintain them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ids = array1.map(function(u){ return u.id });

var unique = array2.filter(function(u) {
  return ids.indexOf(u.id) < 0;
});
```

Comment: Glad it helped. This might not be the most "efficient" performance wise though.